# MySQL Workbench Sync EER Model with many Database (multiple synchronize in one process)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an EER Model and many database (more than 3 database) with same structure.

Until now, I need to sync each database with the EER model one by one.

Is there any ways to sync the EER Model with those database in one time process? (multiple synchronize in one process)

May be there is a function in Workbench? or should I write a script? or may be should I write synchronize code in java? or any others advice?

Thank you.